# understanding priority arrays in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduler

I am trying to understand how scheduler of Linux kernel works

As given on this link

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=NXVkcCjPblcC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q&f=false
and following link
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101760&seqNum=2

struct runque is basic data structure on which a scheduler runs

it is

```
struct runqueue {
    spinlock_t     lock;        /* spin lock which protects this
                                   runqueue */
    unsigned long    nr_running;     /* number of runnable tasks */
    unsigned long    nr_switches;     /* number of contextswitches */
    unsigned long    expired_timestamp;  /* time of last array swap */
    unsigned long    nr_uninterruptible; /* number of tasks in
                                               uinterruptible sleep */
    struct task_struct *curr;        /* this processor's currently
                                      running task */
    struct task_struct *idle;        /* this processor's idle task */
    struct mm_struct  *prev_mm;      /* mm_struct of last running task
                                      */
    struct prio_array  *active;       /* pointer to the active priority
                                        array */
    struct prio_array  *expired;      /* pointer to the expired
                                         priority array */
    struct prio_array  arrays[2];      /* the actual priority arrays */
    int         prev_cpu_load[NR_CPUS];/* load on each processor */
    struct task_struct *migration_thread;  /* the migration thread on this
                                              processor */
    struct list_head  migration_queue;   /* the migration queue for this
                                             processor */
    atomic_t      nr_iowait;      /* number of tasks waiting on I/O
                                   */
}
```

above has two members

```
struct prio_array  *active;       /* pointer to the active priority
                                    array */
struct prio_array  *expired;      /* pointer to the expired priority array */
```

and struct prio_array is defined as

```
struct prio_array {
    int        nr_active;      /* number of tasks */ 
    unsigned long   bitmap[BITMAP_SIZE]; /* priority bitmap */
    struct list_head queue[MAX_PRIO];   /* priority queues */
};
```

I am not clear with following sentence

**Question 1)**
`Each priority array contains one queue of runnable processors per priority level.`

among the above definition of `struct prio_array` **where is the que of runnable processors**

then it says

> ```
> The priority arrays also contain a priority bitmap used to
> ```
>
> efficiently discover the highest priority runnable task in the  system.

then it says 
"With 140 priorities and 32-bit words, this is five."

how does it comes at conclusion that this is five what is mathematical calculation behind it?

the above are excerpts from chapter 4 of book which are published in 2nd link both contain same text.Just posted here for sake of clarity.

**UPDATE1 **
based on comments I just wanted to clarify what I am asking 
author says

> BITMAP_SIZE is the size that an array of unsigned long typed
>   variables would have to be to provide one bit for each valid priority
>   level. With 140 priorities and 32-bit words, this is five.

**Question 2)**
What I am not clear is one bit for each priority level is given and 140 priority levels are there so how is the array size coming 5 I am not getting the logic of BITMAP_SIZE calculation not 140/32=5

it has some thing to do with following paragraph

```
    When a task of a given priority becomes runnable (that is,  
 its state becomes TASK_RUNNING), the corresponding bit in the 
bitmap is set to one. For example, if a task with priority seven is 
runnable, then bit seven is set
```

on links which is where array

```
 unsigned long   bitmap[BITMAP_SIZE]; /* priority bitmap */
```

is set so basically what I am not clear is how this array is getting set and see the Question 1 also if I am able to explain correctly.

**UPDATE 2 and explanation of answer below**

With the answer below I am just adding a small explanation it might help some one in future 
if they come here basically

scheduler maintains a runque and the list of runnable processes each runnable process is on exactly one runqueue, the articles to whose links I gave have considered multi processor systems with many run ques, coming back to our situation with one processor and a runque with processes at various priority levels

there are 140 priority levels each priority levels has different processes in TASK_RUNNING state say for example there can be many  process of priority 8 and so on (I took 8 just as example)
 struct runque points to priority array which tells

```
btimap[BITMAP] /* this is the priority level 
struct list_head /* points to the start of list of processes of that run level
```

So a runque points to priority array and from priority array you can easily get the process 
which needs to be executed in O(1) time.

Comment: That you need 5 words to hold 140 bits?

Comment: see 2 to power of five is 32 then how is it 140

Comment: I rather see it as 140/32 is slightly more than 4 words, so make it 5.

Comment: A **word** is 32 bits. The author says five **words** are needed for 140 bits.

Comment: Ok I get you the author says ` BITMAP_SIZE is the size that an array of unsigned long typed variables would have to be to provide one bit for each valid priority level. With 140 priorities and 32-bit words, this is five.` What I am not clear is one bit for each priority level is given and 140 priority levels are there so how is the array size coming 5 I am not getting the logic of BITMAP_SIZE calculation not 140/32=5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking how to find the right bit in the array?

Something like this:

```
int bitmap_idx = priority/BITS_PER_WORD;
int bitmap_bit = priority%BITS_PER_WORD;

isSet = ( bitmap[bitmap_idx]&(1<<bitmap_bit) );  //test
bitmap[bitmap_idx] |= 1<<bitmap_bit;             //set
```

Comment: yes you got me right with your logic I did the calculation if priority=7 then by your logic `bitmap[0]|=1<<7` which means bitmap[0]=128  correct me if I am wrong